# liboss static declaration of ‘ioctl’ follows non-static declaration

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a program that includes liboss's  file, but when I compile I get the following error.

```
In file included from test.c:1:
/opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h:342: error: static declaration of ‘ioctl’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:97: error: previous declaration of ‘ioctl’ was here
/opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h:353: error: static declaration of ‘open’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h:464: error: previous declaration of ‘open’ was here
/opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h:363: error: static declaration of ‘close’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/unistd.h:476: error: previous declaration of ‘close’ was here
/opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h:366: error: conflicting types for ‘write’
/usr/include/unistd.h:535: error: previous declaration of ‘write’ was here
```

The line where the first error occurs is this one.

@ soundcard.h

```
static inline int LIBOSS_IOCTL (int x, unsigned long y,...)
{
    int result;

    va_list l;
    va_start(l,y);
    result = liboss_ioctl(x,y,l);
    va_end (l);
    return result;
}
```

@ ioctl.h

```
__BEGIN_DECLS
int ioctl(int, unsigned long, ...);
__END_DECLS
```

Is there any way in which I can monkey-patch soundcard.h so that this won't be an issue?

Thnx! A.

Specs: Mac OSX 10.7.4, gcc i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `liboss` is trying to provide an oss-compatible soundcard interface on a system where that's non-native by redefining the `ioctl` function to provide the OSS `ioctl` operations without the kernel having support for them. If this is the case, you need to make sure `sys/ioctl.h` (or any header that might include it) does not get included in the same source files that use `soundcard.h`.

Comment: Tried it and now it skips only to the following error (see question). There is an #undef directive a little below in soundcard.h. Wouldn't that do the trick? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `static` to `/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:97`, `/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h:464`, `/usr/include/unistd.h:476` and `/usr/include/unistd.h:535` (and undo those changes again after compilation).

In `/opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h:366` replace `int` by `ssize_t`.

```
# add static
sudo nano +97 /usr/include/sys/ioctl.h
- int  ioctl(int, unsigned long, ...);
+ static int  ioctl(int, unsigned long, ...);

# replace int by ssize_t
sudo nano +366 /opt/local/include/liboss/soundcard.h
- static inline int LIBOSS_WRITE (int x, const void *y, size_t l)
+ static inline ssize_t LIBOSS_WRITE (int x, const void *y, size_t l)
```